# Cannot call Stored procedure Error code 1305

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

The database is about exam scheduling and this is the main stored procedure which is about scheduling courses on a given date.
I created the procedure but when I try to call it says the procedure is not found.

I've looked through the code but can't find syntax errors, the procedure itself does not have compilation errors, (but that may be because I have to use delimiters?)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE schedule_course(IN in_code CHAR(3), IN in_date DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE complete BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE module_code CHAR(3);
DECLARE module_c CURSOR FOR
SELECT course_code FROM module WHERE course_code = in_code;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET complete = TRUE;

IF (DAYOFWEEK(in_date) = 6 OR 7) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE TEXT = 'Cannot schedule start date on a weekend'
END IF;

OPEN module_c;

mainloop : LOOP
FETCH NEXT FROM module_c INTO module_code;

IF complete THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE TEXT = 'Something something'
END IF;

INSERT INTO SESSION (`code`, `date`, room)
VALUES
(module_code, in_date, NULL)

LEAVE mainloop;
END LOOP;
DELIMITER ;

CALL schedule_course(WSD, CURDATE())
```

Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE cameron.schedule_course does not exist

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MESSAGE TEXT = 'Cannot schedule start date on a weekend'`

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors in your procedure - So it should not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql 8 show a lot of errors.
I corrected them, the logic is sound but of course you have to check it,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`  PROCEDURE schedule_course(IN in_code CHAR(3), IN in_date DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE complete BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE module_code CHAR(3);
  DECLARE module_c CURSOR FOR
  SELECT course_code FROM module WHERE course_code = in_code;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
   SET complete = TRUE;

  IF (DAYOFWEEK(in_date) = 6 OR DAYOFWEEK(in_date) = 7) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot schedule start date on a weekend';
  END IF;

  OPEN module_c;

  mainloop : LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM module_c INTO module_code;

    IF complete THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Something something';
    END IF;

   INSERT INTO SESSION (`code`, `date`, room)
   VALUES
    (module_code, in_date, NULL);

  LEAVE mainloop;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE module_c;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you have not  an end  (END $$)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE schedule_course(IN in_code CHAR(3), IN in_date DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE complete BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE module_code CHAR(3);
DECLARE module_c CURSOR FOR
SELECT course_code FROM module WHERE course_code = in_code;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET complete = TRUE;

IF (DAYOFWEEK(in_date) = 6 OR 7) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE TEXT = 'Cannot schedule start date on a weekend'
END IF;

OPEN module_c;

mainloop : LOOP
FETCH NEXT FROM module_c INTO module_code;

IF complete THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE TEXT = 'Something something'
END IF;

INSERT INTO SESSION (`code`, `date`, room)
VALUES
(module_code, in_date, NULL)

LEAVE mainloop;
END LOOP;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```